# unconfirmed payment

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I was trying to purchase something online using bitcoin.  after submitting the payment I got a screen that said "Payment has been received but needs 2 bitcoin confirmations to be accepted. Please return to merchant and allow up to 30 minutes for the bitcoin network to confirm payment."  after 30 minutes I received a screen that said "unconfirmed transaction."    What do I need to do now?   The amount has been withdrawn from my wallet but the merchant has not received payment.  Is the money just gone now?

Comment: Did you include a transaction fee with your payment?  Are you able to see the transaction on sites like http://blockchain.info?  The money is not gone, and most likely it will eventually be confirmed if you just wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

If you've gotten that far, it means that your transaction was sent and received by the network and also by the vendor.

"Unconfirmed Transaction" means that the transaction has been sent but has not been made permanent in the blockchain yet.  Blocks are mined on average every 10 minutes, but due to random chance this time can increase to over an hour at some points.  You just have to wait until these confirmations occur and then the vendor will accept your payment.

If you want to watch newly mined blocks in real time, check out https://blockchain.info/.  On their homepage, the most recently mined blocks are listed and newly mined blocks will appear as soon as they're mined.